# How to customize legend of a chart with Google Scripts

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script

I've been trying to find an answer to this, but I have had no such luck. I was wondering if it is at all possible to add some customization to a legend of a Chart with google scripts? If so could maybe you guys point me in the right direction of how to accomplish this? thanks in advance.

here are the options that I have set so far.

```
options = {'title':'Production',
                'width':1366,
                'height':768,
                'vAxis': {'format': '$#,##0.00;($#,##0.00)',
                'title': 'Money'},
                'hAxis': {'title': 'Month'}
                };
```

Sincerely,
Sicariuxs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example of how you can use to customize the legend of the chart with Google Charts:

```
 var options = {
          //sliceVisibilityThreshold: 0.01,
          chartArea:{left:10,top:0,width:'100%',height:'100%'},
          height: 300,
          legend: { position: 'right', textStyle: {fontSize: 7}},
          pieSliceText: 'none',
          colors:['#03A9F4','#0091EA']
        };
```

Comment: Hey @Vadim Solovey Thank you for your help! This really helps!